# Get stdout as a fd in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'd like ANSI C style `stdout` operations on `stdout`.

That is, I'd like to be able to treat a file descriptor and `stdout` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can use [`fs.read`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/fs.html#fs.read) to read from a file descriptor and [`fs.write`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/fs.html#fs.write) to write to a file descriptor.

Since `process.stdout` is a Stream it has a property `fd` which refers to the file descriptor.

`fs.write(process.stdout.fd, new Buffer("hello world"), 0, 11, 0)`

Note that the `fd` property is undocumented and might disappear in later versions of node.

Since this isn't documented anywhere you basically have to [read the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1238)

Comment: The `process.std***.fd` properties are [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdoutfd) nowadays. TypeScript doesn't know about that though, so it's useful to know the `fd` of stdout is always `1`.